# ui-sref error when use special character in params

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here is my code

```
<a ui-sref="exeprofile({pname:@event})"></a>
```

there is a **'@'** in the paramater ,so I get error tips like this

> 'Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 7-7 [@] in expression [{pname:@event}].'

I'm confused about how to pass `@event` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` is not valid sign for JavaScript variables naming: [Valid JavaScript variable names](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers)

So I expect, that `@event` is a string value..., then this should work:

```
<a ui-sref="exeprofile({pname:'@event'})"></a>
```

Comment: @ Radim Köhler First ,your answer solved my problm. But I want to describe my problem clearly again in case I understand right. In my code ,@event is not a variable ,it's a value. code like this  <a ui-sref="exeprofile({pname:full.name})"></a>  the variable is full.name when the the value for full.name is @event ,it throw error. With your suggestion ,I modify it to <a  ui-sref="exeprofile({pname:'+'\''+full.name+'\''+'})">  ,and it works now.  But I think this is not because of the variable valid problem yes,because here the variable is full.name ,@event is the value.Am i right?

Comment: If I do understand you properly, you'd like to understand why to use `'`? The reason is, because we pass a string. And not a variable. Does this help?

Comment: since the variable is full.name ,the @event is a value from runtime . maybe the error is because angularjs-ui-router does not support @ here,can you give any comments?@Radim Köhler

Comment: For sure UI-Router, does not support `@` sign. Because it is not supported by JS. It could be only a string. And that's why it mus be inside of a `'`. Better?